# Kernel of a matrix with a 0 column

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm trying to find the $$
        ker\begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & 2 \\
        0 & 2 & 4 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

I would usually write the linearly dependent columns in terms of the others. For example: $$ v_1+2v_2-v_3=0 $$

In this case I'm not sure what to do with column $ v_1 $ which consists entirely of $0$s. It would give me a basis that looks like

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
          1 \\
          2 \\
          -1 \\
        \end{bmatrix} ,
\begin{bmatrix}
          2 \\
          2 \\
          -1 \\
        \end{bmatrix},...,
\begin{bmatrix}
          a \\
          2 \\
          -1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
for all $a$.

I know I should have a 2-dimensional basis, though. I suspect I'm wrong in my interpretation of linear (in)dependence? Or am I missing some obvious way to combine these specific columns?

Comment: Note that "Kyle Numbers" is not standard terminology. A quick googling suggests that it is an idiosyncratic name used by only one particular linear algebra textbook, apparently not in a terribly well defined way.

Comment: so it is... thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the matrix $A$. Then to find $\ker A$, we row-reduce the augmented matrix $[A \mid \vec 0]$ to obtain:
$$
\left[ \begin{array}{ccc|c}
0 & 1 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array} \right]
$$
Hence, $v_2$ is the basic variable that is to be expressed in terms of the free variables $v_1$ and $v_3$. Since:
$$
v_2 + 2v_3 = 0 \iff v_2 = -2v_3
$$
it follows that the desired kernel is the set of all vectors of the form:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
v_1 \\ v_2 \\ v_3
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
v_1 \\ -2v_3 \\ v_3
\end{bmatrix}
=
v_1\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\ 0 \\ 0
\end{bmatrix}
+ v_3
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\ -2 \\ 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $v_1, v_3$ are any real numbers.